# Specification for Tally SOAP API

Tags: python, financial, erp

Where can I find specifications for Tally's SOAP API?
And does anyone know of any python libraries for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Tally supports a SOAP based interface, rather it does support a decent XML/HTTP interface. I tried to play around with it, using Java. Maybe this helps: http://subbaraman.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/playing-with-tally-software/

Comment: I searched and searched. I wonder how come i didnt find that :D