# How to connect "Tally ODBC" through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Tally.ERP9, I haven't found anything about Tally ODBC connection on net. I want a python script to connect with Tally database. Can I get some links for that and some python scripts to connect tally database using Tally ODBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it supports ODBC, you might try pyodbc: http://pyodbc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of direct connection engine is available or not but you can have a look at this post may it will help

[Specification for Tally SOAP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468833/specification-for-tally-soap-api)